# How to add attributes to Elements from an Ajax Request

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, request

I'm having a problem here and can't find a way to solve it!

Let me explain what I am trying to do:

I have a form to dispatch orders.

Select a destination:

```
<select name="destination" id="destination">
    <option value="d1">d1</option>
    <option value="d2">d2</option>
    <option value="dN">dN</option>
</select>
```

Select an option:

```
<input type="radio" value="report" id="report" /> Report
```

When I select a target and click one of the options a ajax request is done to fetch a list of orders:

```
jQuery(function() {
  var destination = jQuery('#destination').val();
  jQuery('#result').html(''></div>');
  jQuery('#result').html('<em style="color:red">Please, wait! Sending your request...</em>');
  jQuery('#result').load('report.php?destination =' + destination + '&cache=' + Math.random() );
});
```

The text reponse is so loaded into a DIV#result.

Inside this div has a list of orders and theirs related products to be delivered.
If one or more products weren't marked as in stock, i append a script to the end of "order" loop:

```
<?php
// result.php 
$allInStock = true;
// loop orders
// inside orders check if related products are in stock 
// $allInStock is set to false if product is not in stock
?>
<?php if( $allInStock == false ) : ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( function() {
    jQuery('#checkbox-<?php echo $res['order_id'];?>').attr('disabled', true);
    jQuery('#link-<?php echo $res['orders_id'];?>').attr('href', 'javascript:void;');
    jQuery('#td-<?php echo $res['orders_id'];?>').click(function(){alert("This order can't be delivered!")});
  }
);
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

As you can figure out, the result will be as expected.
But if I click again in the Report button, it loads the text response as expected but the jquery code doesn't work! Even it been loaded.

Any clue? I don't have the less ideia of what to be done, and couldn't find how to report myself to Mr. Google.

Thanks in Advance! :D

Comment: Use the load callback function

Comment: I solved the problem by loading jquery.js inside the ajax requested file! Any other option?